# Why does this program loop?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have written the following program, and I was wondering if the behavior of it (1) will always loop; or (2) it has unexpected behavior. I know that I'm missing a `ret` at the end of the function (and this makes the program run fine), but I was wondering why the program loops when it's not included:

```
# file.s
.include "utils.s"

.data
str:    .string "Tony"

.text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $str,   %rdi
    call print_string
    mov $10, %edi
    mov $SYS_EXIT, %eax
    syscall
```

```
# utils.o
SYS_EXIT    = 60
SYS_WRITE   = 1
SYS_STDOUT  = 1

print_string:
    # void print_string(char *)
    mov %rdi,       %rsi
    mov $1,         %rdi
    mov $4,         %rdx
    mov $SYS_WRITE, %eax
    syscall
```

To assemble/link/run:

```
$ as utils.s -o utils.o && as file.s -o file.o && ld file.o utils.o -o file
$ ./file
```

When viewing this in `gdb` after the `print_string.syscall` it goes back to `mov $str, %rdi` but why does that occur?

Note: it `segfaults` when all in one file, but when the `print_string` is moved to a second file it loops so maybe this is more related to the assembling/linking than the code itself.

Comment: single-step it in a debugger to see what bytes of machine code execution falls into after falling off the end of what you wrote.  If this was a simple static executable, it would probably just be zeros and would fault on the `add %al, (%rax)` instruction that `00 00` decodes to.  Show an actual [mcve] of how exactly you built this into an executable.  If you linked `print_string` *first*, then execution falls through from it to `_start`, opposite of what you showed in the question.  This is why SO questions need real [mcve]s, not something you made up that you think might be equivalent.

Comment: UB.  You might have hit a jump, you might have popped a register into a jump location, many things could cause this.  You are reading past the end of your program though so, who knows...

Comment: As it is now, your execution already executes the print_string twice.  Did you not want a return on your start function as well to prevent that?

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes updated with your suggestion

Comment: You did `.include "utils.s"`, so the `call print_string` will call the copy of `print_string` you included, not the one in the other `.o` file (which isn't `.globl` so isn't even reachable).  Don't put code in a file you're going to `.include`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see, thanks for the explanation. What would be the correct way to call a function from another file after making sure its `.globl` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did `.include "utils.s"`, so the `call print_string` will call the copy of `print_string` you included, not the one in the other `.o` file (which isn't `.globl` so isn't even reachable from other files, like a `static void foo(char*)` function in C).

Execution falls through from the end of `print_string` to `_start`.

**Don't put code in a file you're going to `.include`, *only* definitions of constants and macros.**  If you did use `.globl print_string`, then you'd have two conflicting definitions of the same global symbol.  And of course you'd be duplicating the definition of every function into every other file that included it, defeating the purpose of linking and functions.

---

In more detail, your `file.s` after .include is processed will look like this:

```
# implicit  .text  - the default section at the top of the file
SYS_EXIT    = 60
SYS_WRITE   = 1
SYS_STDOUT  = 1

print_string:
    # void print_string(char *)
    mov %rdi,       %rsi
    mov $1,         %rdi
    mov $4,         %rdx
    mov $SYS_WRITE, %eax
    syscall

.data
str:    .string "Tony"

.text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $str,   %rdi
    call print_string
    mov $10, %edi
    mov $SYS_EXIT, %eax
    syscall
```

Notice that `ld` won't complain if you omit `utils.o` because this file has no unresolved symbol references.

Comment: Oh, I see. So basically the `call print_string` is more-or-less (at least functionally, since in this case the return address doesn't matter since no `ret` is called) just doing a `jmp print_string` and since the include is above it, it will just keep looping back. Is that accurate?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: Yes.  It will eventually segfault when pushing a return address overflows the 8MiB stack space, but that will take a lot of slow write system calls, especially if you let it print to a terminal.