# Proper way to do imports with gas

Tags: assembly, x86, linker, gnu-assembler

From my two previous questions -- one related to importing constants and one related to importing functions -- [Import constants in x86 with gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016443/import-constants-in-x86-with-gas) and [Why does this program loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016798/why-does-this-program-loop), I was wondering if the following accurately summarizes how to do imports using `as` in assembly with an example:

```
# constants.s
SYS_EXIT        = 60
SYS_WRITE       = 1
STDOUT_FILENO   = 1
```

```
# utils.s
.include "constants.s"

# Global function
.globl print_string
print_string:

    call get_string_length
    mov %eax, %edx
    mov %rdi,       %rsi
    mov $1,         %edi
    mov $SYS_WRITE, %eax
    syscall
    ret

# Local function (for now)
get_string_length:
    mov $0, %eax # string length goes in rax
  L1_get_string_length:
    cmp $0, (%rdi, %rax,)
    je L2_get_string_length
    inc %eax
    jmp L1_get_string_length
  L2_get_string_length:
    ret
```

```
# file.s
.include "constants.s"

.data
str:    .string "Hellllloooo"

.text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $str,   %rdi
    call print_string
    mov $0, %edi
    mov $SYS_EXIT, %eax
    syscall
```

If my understanding is correct then:

1. Functions need to be made `.globl` to be accessible to other object files during linking. Both those object files need to be linked together, for example: `ld file.o utils.o -o file`.
2. Definitions or macros can be imported/included using [`.include "filename"`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC97). What this does is essentially copy/paste the contents of that included file into where that directive is. We do not need to link -- or do anything additional beyond -- the `.include` statement of that file. Does it matter if multiple files use that same include statement?
3. Any other things I may be missing or tips with imports, includes, etc? Does `.include` take a standard unix path, for example I could do: `.include "../constants.s"` or `.include "/home/constants.s"`?

Comment: Note that while you can use `.include` to make constants visible, you can also declare the constants as global the same way you do with functions and let the linker figure this out.  However, note that this means that the constant must be used everywhere in the program with the same value.  Even in 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @fuz thanks for the feedback. How would i make a constant global? Something like: `.globl SYS_EXIT; SYS_EXIT: .int 60` ?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: That's a different thing, because in that case `$SYS_EXIT` will not give you the number 60, but an address in memory where the number 60 is stored.  You'd have to change your immediate move `mov $SYS_EXIT, %eax` to `mov SYS_EXIT, %eax`, which although it's not obvious in A&T& notation, is a load from memory, and less efficient.

Comment: Linker symbols are intended to be addresses, not numerical constants, and so it's not so obvious how to set one to a constant.  It can probably be done but one normally doesn't.  One issue is that making it a linker symbol will typically make it impossible to do any significant compile-time arithmetic on it; you're limited to whatever relocation transformations are available.

Comment: My inclination would be to treat it just like C: includes should contain macros and compile-time constants only.  (In C you would also have declarations, but assembly doesn't really have any such thing.)  Multiple files with actual code should be assembled separately and linked together.

Comment: The simplest way to see whether full paths work is to test it.  I strongly suspect that they do.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249  Just add `.globl SYS_EXIT` to your existing `SYS_EXIT = 60`.

Comment: @NateEldredge  Symbols can be numeric constants if desired.  There's nothing wrong with doing so.  Those are realised as offsets into the absolute section.

Comment: @fuz: One reason to `.include` is to let the assembler choose a shorter encoding based on a known numeric value.  e.g. if you did `lea SYS_EXIT(%rdx), %eax` with a hypothetical known-zero EDX, you'd get a disp8 if the assembler could see the value was 60, otherwise you'd get a disp32.  Not an issue with `mov` though, where GAS will assemble `mov $unknown_symbol, %rax` to `mov $sign_extended_imm32, %rax`, same as with a known value.  Unlike NASM it won't optimize it to `mov $imm32, %eax`, and it won't use `movabs` unless you tell it to.

Comment: @fuz: But if you have other constants you do normally use with `add` or `sub`, or other ALU instructions, you want to make sure the assembler can see their small numeric values.  Oh, I see Nate's answer already illustrates this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are four possible ways to "import constants from a file".

### 1. Using `.include` and `=` (uses gas only)

constants.inc:

```
    ANSWER_TO_LIFE = 0x42
```

code.s:

```
    .include "constants.inc"
    mov $ANSWER_TO_LIFE, %eax
    add $ANSWER_TO_LIFE, %ebx   # best encoding
    mov $(ANSWER_TO_LIFE+17), %ecx
    mov $(ANSWER_TO_LIFE*ANSWER_TO_LIFE), %edx
```

Building:

```
as -o code.o code.s         # or gcc -c code.s
ld -o prog code.o code2.o   # or gcc -o prog code.o code2.o
```

This is the most straightforward approach using only the features of the GNU assembler itself.  I have named the include file `.inc` instead of `.s` to indicate that it is meant to be included into other assembly source files, but not assembled on its own (as it would produce an object file containing nothing).  You can include it into as many different files as need to use the constant, and relative or absolute paths are supported (`.include ../include/constants.inc`, `.include /usr/share/include/constants.inc` both work).

Since the assembler knows the value of the constant, it can choose the best instruction encodings.  For instance, [the x86 `add $imm, %reg32`  instruction has two possible encodings](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add): a 6-byte encoding with a 32-bit immediate operand (opcode 0x81), and a smaller 3-byte encoding with an 8-bit sign-extended immediate operand (opcode 0x83).  Since 0x42 fits in 8 bits, the latter is available here, so `add $0x42, %ebx` can be encoded in three bytes as `83 c3 42`.  The example also shows that we can perform arbitrary arithmetic on the constant at assembly time.

### 2. Using the C preprocessor (most common in practice)

constants.h:

```
#define ANSWER_TO_LIFE 0x42
```

code.S:

```
#include "constants.h"
    mov $ANSWER_TO_LIFE, %eax
    add $ANSWER_TO_LIFE, %ebx   # also gets best encoding
    mov $(ANSWER_TO_LIFE*ANSWER_TO_LIFE), %ecx
```

Building:

```
gcc -c code.S              # can't use as by itself here
ld -o prog code.o code2.o  # or gcc if you prefer
```

In this approach, you run the C preprocessor `cpp` on the source file before giving it to the assembler.  The `gcc` command will do this for you if you name the source file with `.S` (note case sensitivity).  Then C-style `#include` and `#define` directives are expanded, so the assembler only sees `mov $0x42, %eax` without any indication that the constant ever had a name.

This approach has the advantage that the file `constants.h` can equally well be included into C code, which is helpful in the very common situation when your project mixes C and assembly source.  As such, it is the approach I've most commonly seen "in the wild".  (Practically no real-life programs are written entirely in assembly.)

In your original use case, where the constant in question was a Linux system call number, this approach is best because the relevant include file has already been written by the kernel developers, and you can get it with `#include <asm/unistd.h>`.  This file defines all the system call numbers with macro names of the form `__NR_exit`.

### 3. As a symbol resolved at link time (somewhat awkward)

constants.s:

```
    .global ANSWER_TO_LIFE
    ANSWER_TO_LIFE = 0x42
```

code.s:

```
    mov $ANSWER_TO_LIFE, %eax
    add $ANSWER_TO_LIFE, %ebx   # not the optimal encoding
    mov $(ANSWER_TO_LIFE+17), %ecx
    #mov $(ANSWER_TO_LIFE*ANSWER_TO_LIFE), %ecx # error
```

Building:

```
as -o constants.o constants.s          # or gcc -c constants.s
as -o code.o code.s                    # etc
ld -o prog constants.o code.o code2.o  # or gcc
```

This is the approach mentioned by @fuz in comments.  It treats the symbol `ANSWER_TO_LIFE` like a label that happens to be located at absolute address `0x42`.  The assembler treats it as it would any other label; it doesn't know its address at assembly time, so it leaves it as an unresolved reference in the object file `code.o`, which the linker will eventually resolve.

The only real benefit of this approach that I can see is that if we want to change the value of the constant, say to 0x43, we don't have to re-run the assembler on all our source files `code.s code2.s ...`; we only have to re-assemble `constant.s` and re-link.  So we save a little bit of build time, but not much because assembling code is usually pretty fast anyway.  (It might make a difference if we referenced the symbol from C or C++ code, for which compilation is slower, but see below.)

But there are some notable disadvantages:

- Since the assembler doesn't know the value of the constant, it has to assume it could be of the largest size valid for each instruction in which  it is used.  In particular, in `add $ANSWER_TO_LIFE, %ebx`, it can't assume that the 8-bit 0x83 encoding will be usable, so it has to select the larger 32-bit encoding.  So the instruction `add $ANSWER_TO_LIFE, %ebx` has to be assembled as `81 c3 00 00 00 00`, where the `00 00 00 00` is replaced by the linker with the correct value `42 00 00 00`.  But we end up using 6 bytes on an instruction that ideally could have been encoded using 3 bytes.
- On the flip side of this, immediate [`mov`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) into a 64-bit register also has two encodings: one taking a sign-extended 32-bit immediate `mov $imm32, %reg64` (opcode c7 with REX.W prefix), which is 7 bytes, and another taking a full 64-bit immediate `mov $imm64, %reg64` (opcodes b8-b4 with REX.W), which is 10 bytes.  The assembler will by default select the 32-bit form, because the 64-bit one is really long and rarely needed.  But if it turns out that your symbol has a value that doesn't fit in 32 bits, you'll get an error at link time ("relocation truncated to fit"), and you'll have to go back and force the 64-bit encoding by using the mnemonic `movabs`.  If you had used approaches 1 or 2, the assembler would have known the value of your constant and would have selected the appropriate encoding in the first place.
- If we want to do build-time arithmetic on the constant, we're limited to whatever arithmetic can be represented as relocations in the object file.  Constant offsets work, so `mov $(ANSWER_TO_LIFE+17), %ecx` is okay; the object file tells the linker to fill in the relevant bytes with the value of the symbol `ANSWER_TO_LIFE` plus the constant 17.  (For actual labels, you'd want this for something like accessing a member from a static `struct`.)  But more general operations like multiplication aren't supported, because people wouldn't normally want to do those on addresses, so `mov $(ANSWER_TO_LIFE*ANSWER_TO_LIFE), %edx` results in an error from the assembler.  If we need the square of the answer to life, we have to write a `mul` instruction to compute it at run time, which would be no fun if this is code that is called frequently and needs to be fast.

The constant can also be accessed from C code linked into our project, but it has to be treated like a label (address of a variable), which makes it look weird.  We have to write something like

```
extern void *ANSWER_TO_LIFE;
printf("The answer is %lu\n", (unsigned long)&ANSWER_TO_LIFE);
```

If we try to write something more natural-looking like

```
extern unsigned long ANSWER_TO_LIFE;
printf("The answer is %lu\n", ANSWER_TO_LIFE);
```

the program will try to fetch the value from memory address 0x42, which will crash.

(Also, even in the first example, the assembly output by the compiler uses the `mov` mnemonic which again leads to the assembler selecting a 32-bit move.  If `ANSWER_TO_LIFE` were larger than `2^32` then linking would fail, and this time it's not as easy to fix.  AFAIK you'd need to give gcc an appropriate option to tell it to change its [code model](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/03/understanding-the-x64-code-models), which would cause *every* address load to use the less efficient 64-bit form, and you'd have to do this for your entire program.)

### 4. As a value stored in memory and fetched at runtime (inefficient)

constants.s:

```
    .section .rodata
    .global answer_to_life
answer_to_life:
    .int 0x42
```

code.s:

```
    mov answer_to_life, %eax
    add answer_to_life, %ebx

    # mov answer_to_life+17, %ecx # not valid, no such instruction exists
    mov answer_to_life, %ecx
    add $17, %ecx   # needs two instructions

    # mov answer_to_life*answer_to_life, %edx # not valid
    mov answer_to_life, %eax
    mul %eax  # clobbers %edx
```

Building:

```
as -o constants.o constants.s
as -o code.o code.s
ld -o prog constants.o code.o code2.o
```

This approach is the equivalent of having `const int answer_to_life = 42;` in a C program (though C++ is different).  The value 42 is stored in our program's memory and whenever we need to access it, we need an instruction that reads from memory; we can no longer encode it as an immediate within each instruction.  This will typically be slower to execute.  If we need to do any arithmetic on it, we have to write code to load it into a register and execute appropriate instructions at runtime, which takes cycles and code space.

I've changed the name here to lower case to match the convention for variables located in memory, as opposed to "compile time" constants which this no longer is.  Also note the different syntax in the instructions; `mov answer_to_life, %eax`, without the `$` sign, is a load from memory instead of an immediate move.  `$answer_to_life` in this example gives you the address of the variable instead (which by a happy coincidence is `0x402000` in my test program).  If you want to be able to build a position-independent executable, which is the norm for modern Linux programs, you need to write `answer_to_life(%rip)` instead.

For the reasons noted above, this approach is not ideal for numerical constants that truly are known at compile time, but I include it for completeness and because you asked about it in comments.

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time. What a great and very helpful answer!